# Asterisk / FreePBX: Calls to internal extensions require users to press Dial

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

Using FreePBX 14 and the Cisco SPA504g phone, when my users dial outbound US number (e.g., 15555551212) the calls automatically dial. However, when the dial 555 for an internal extension, they have to press Dial to complete the call.

How do I set the phones to dial automatically when a 3-digit extension beginning with 5 is dialed?

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the 'dialplan' in your phone.  Edit your phone settings and look at the dialplan; you will notice 10 digit calls cause an immediate dial (or within seconds), while <7 digit calls likely dont.

Adjust your dialplan so 3 digit calls are handled like 10 digit calls.  I don't have SPA504g phone to try but the dialplan should be obvious.